# Como controlar as linhas entre a UITableView principal e a UITableView do UISearchBar?

Tags: objective-c, filtro, uisearchbar, uitableview

Estou implementando uma tabela com campo de busca, e estou usando `UISearchBar`.

Possuo duas variáveis no app: um `NSMutableArray` para os dados originais, e outro `NSMutableArray` para os dados filtrados.

Quando a tabela é carregada, é usado o `NSMutableArray` com os `dadosOriginais`, e quando eu filtro algo, os dados encontrados são colocados na `NSMutableArray` `dadosFiltrados`. Porém, quando é selecionada a linha na tabela carregada com o filtro, ela mostra o conteúdo de outra informação, e não daquela que aparece no filtro.

Entendendo melhor, parece que quando a tabela é atualizada com os dados filtrados, ela re-indexa as linhas, então por exemplo: o item no array `dadosOriginais` que está na posição 10 muda sua posição quando é filtrado, ficando na posição 1 no array `dadosFiltrados`.
 Então quando é selecionada, ela abre o conteúdo da posição 1 no arrayOriginal e não na posição 10, como deveria ser.

Alguém já teve este problema?

Abaixo meu código:

```
    -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

            static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tabelaPreview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            }

   NSManagedObject *processosLocal = [arrayOriginal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //Exibição de dados quando são filtrados

        if (isFiltrado == YES) {

            // Busca pelo Processo

            // Marca como lido
            if ([[processosLocal   valueForKey:@"lido"] isEqual:@"1"] ) {


                [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f]];
                [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0f]];
                [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dadosFiltrados objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]]];

             // Marca como não lido
            }else{

                [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0f]];
                [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f]];
                [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dadosFiltrados objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]]];

            }

        // Exibe os dados quando não são filtrados
        }else {

            // Marca como lido
            if ([[processosLocal   valueForKey:@"lido"] isEqual:@"1"] ) {

                [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f]];
                [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0f]];
                [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [processosLocal valueForKey:@"processo"]]];

                // Marca como não lido
            }else{

                [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0f]];
                [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f]];
                [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [processosLocal valueForKey:@"processo"]]];

            }
        }
        return cell;
    }
```

Em outras palavras: Como persistir a indexPath.row do `arrayOriginal` no `arrayFiltrado`?

Abaixo o código responsável de fazer o filtro:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

    if (searchText.length == 0) {

        // Ajustando valor da flag booleana
        isFiltrado = NO;
    }else{

        // Ajustando valor da flag booleana
        isFiltrado = YES;

        dadosFiltrados = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (NSString* numeroProcesso in [arrayProcessosLocal valueForKey:@"processo"]) {
            NSRange rangeNumeroProcesso = [numeroProcesso rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

            if (rangeNumeroProcesso.location != NSNotFound) {

                [dadosFiltrados addObject:numeroProcesso];

              }
           }

        }
    // Reload nossa table view

    [tabelaPreview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Você está utilizando uma simples `UISearchBar` ou implementando a solução completa com `UISearchDisplayController`.

Comment: Usando somente `UISearchBar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua *flag* `isFiltrado`, se estiver funcionando corretamente, pode utilizada para verificação em todos os métodos da tabela, por exemplo: `numberOfRowsInSection`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` e `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Então, você definirá de qual vetor virá os seus dados. A questão é só essa, nada com relação ao `indexPath` mas somente ao *data source*.

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSManagedObject *processosLocal;

    if (isFiltrado) {
        processosLocal = [arrayFiltrado objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        processosLocal = [arrayOriginal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Outro exemplo:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (isFiltrado) {
        return [arrayFiltrado count];
    } else {
        return [arrayOriginal count];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sim sim mas estou tentando fazer essa mesma lógica em `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`  pois é la que o conteúdo é apontado

Comment: Certo, mas a logica tem que ser aplicada a todos os métodos do data source. Qual o problema neste que você tentou?

Comment: O problema é que ele mostra corretamente somente um item do objeto, o nome, mas não carrega corretamente os demais itens que não entraram na busca.

Por exemplo imagina dataSourceOriginal com 3 objetos. A posição 1 |B posição 2 |C posição 3

Então vc faz um filtro no nome dos elementos e retorna C, mas no array do filtro, C não esta mais na posição 3, no novo filtro ele está na posição 1. Então quando ele é selecionado, o uitableview, assume a organização do array de itens filtrados, e aponta nod dataSource para a  posição 1, que cai em cima dos dados do elemento A.

Comment: Ah tem uma OBS tbm, os dados estão vindos do Core Data

Comment: O problema não está então na exibição e sim no filtro, no momento que você cria esse novo array. Mas reforçando, que pelo seu código, a exibição ainda parece incorreta.

Comment: bom pelo que ja tenho a exibição do filtro está bem, e responde a buscas corretas. E é exatamente isso, no caso eu teria que replicar o novo array não somente com um elemento, mas sim com os objetos filtrados. Esses objetos vem do core data. Vou reformular a questão com o código que faz o filtro.

Comment: Pronto, já inclui o código que faz o filtro.